# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module.?

Tags: angular, nx

Поставил базовый проект NX Angular с микрофронтендами
но при запуске.
`nx serve myprojectname --devRemotes=customer,supplier,base,admin`.

пишет ошибку при попытке подключить style.js

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
```

Что можно сделать, что б ошибки не было?

Воспроизвести:

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest 
cd [MyProjectName]
nx g @nrwl/angular:host ==remotes=admin,customer,supplier,base
nx run host --devRemotes=base,admin,customer,supplier
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]